# Почему не запускается react-приложение?

Tags: reactjs

[image: Вот что появляется в командной строке]

Нужно запустить react-приложение

Comment: Ты установил пакет, но не создал приложение. Тут же все чётко написано https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: Но я его скачал. Или это не то? Нужно что-то ещё?

Comment: Устанавливаешь пакет `npm install -g create-react-app`, флаг `-g` - глобально. Не хочешь глобально - убираешь флаг. И далее уже можно инициализировать проект:
`npm init react-app my-app`, где `my-app` это название твоего проекта(любое имя).

Если у тебя версия npm 5.2 и выше, то можно пропустить шаг с установкой пакета и просто использовать `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: версию npm можно проверить введя в консоль команду `npm -v`

Comment: https://c.radikal.ru/c21/2003/32/b1ceb6854a1c.png